# No me funciona esta comprobación en JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que hacer un bucle for que recorra del 0 al 100 y que en cada valor de donde la i sea igual a un multiplo de 3, haga un continue y no lo adjunte a la etiqueta p. Pero a la hora de jecutarlo no aparece nada. ¿Alguna idea de que falle?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>u1e12_breakContinue</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            var textoGeneral;
            var multiplo3 = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99];
            
            for (i = 0; i == 100; i++){

                if (multiplo3.includes(i)==true){
                    continue;
                }

                var actual = i;
                textoGeneral = textoGeneral.concat(actual);
                
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textoGeneral;
                
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El bucle for tiene un error, necesitas decirle que lo recorra mientras `i <= 100` .

La variable textoGeneral tienes que asignarle un valor inicial, aunque sea nulo. Si no te da un error a la hora de intentar acceder a él dentro del bucle `for`.

Para la comprobación de si es múltiplo de 3 puedes simplemente comprobar el resto de su división entre 3. Ya que tu opción no es viable si quieres trabajar con números más altos (Por ejemplo para sacar hasta el número 10000).

```js
var textoGeneral = "";

            
            for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++){

                if (i%3==0){
                    continue;
                }

                var actual = i;
                textoGeneral = textoGeneral.concat(actual);
                
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textoGeneral;
                
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>u1e12_breakContinue</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya había redactado yo una solución :( pero bueno, te dejo a ti mi +1 y borro la mía :)

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia

Comment: gracias a ambos me sirvio y entiendo el aporte de optimizacion de no usar un array de elementos y hacer la comprobacion en la condicion del if

Answer (score 1):

También puedes hacerlo en línea:

```js
document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = Array(101).fill(0).map((_, i)=> i + 1)
  .filter(i => i % 3 === 0).join('');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```